# fileupload not working in ajax

Tags: php, php-5.6

i have **file upload** form field,i select one gif','png' ,'jpg' means it will work,and i am select any other file .mp3,.php file it will give error like this `**SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected non-whitespace character after JSON data at line 1 column 73 of the JSON data**`.i want to **file type** check and **file size** after that i want to insert the value,but don't know how to do this,i think my PHP code should be wrong...

```js
<?php
 $filename  = basename($_FILES['file']['name']);
 $extension = pathinfo($filename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
 $new_name= md5($filename.time()).'.'.$extension;
 if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], "horoscope/".$new_name)) {
 // FILE TYPE CHECKING
  $allowed =  array('gif','png' ,'jpg');
  if(!in_array($extension,$allowed) ) {
  $newuser = array('photoname' => $new_name, "message" => "error");
  if($_FILES['file']['size'] > 2459681 ){
   $newuser = array('photoname' => $new_name, "message" => "filesize is to large");
  }else{
   $newuser = array('photoname' => $new_name, "message" => "success");
  }
  echo json_encode($newuser);
 }
 else{
  $newuser = array('photoname' => $new_name, "message" => "success");
 } 
 echo json_encode($newuser);

}else{
 //echo "Error";
 $newuser = array("message" => "file is not moving");
 echo json_encode($newuser);
} 
?>
   <script type="text/javascript">
                  $(document).ready(function(){
                    $("#user-submit").click(function(event){
                      event.preventDefault();
                      if($("form#newUserForm").valid()){
                      var formData = new FormData();
                      var formData = new FormData($('#newUserForm')[0]);
                      formData.append('file', $('input[type=file]')[0].files[0]);
                        $.ajax({
                        url: 'horoscope-check.php',
                        type: 'POST',
                        data: formData,
                        async: false,
                        cache: false,
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        success: function (data) {
                            var res=jQuery.parseJSON(data);// convert the json
                            console.log(res);
                        },
                        
                    });

                      return false;
                      }else{
                        console.log("false");
                      }
                    });
                  });
                </script>
```

```html
<form class="form-horizontal form-bordered" method="POST" id="newUserForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
          <div class="form-group">
            <label class="col-md-3 control-label">Photo Upload</label>
            <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="fileupload fileupload-new" data-provides="fileupload">
            <div class="input-append">
            <div class="uneditable-input">
            <i class="fa fa-file fileupload-exists"></i>
            <span class="fileupload-preview"></span>
            </div>
            <span class="btn btn-default btn-file">
            <span class="fileupload-exists">Change</span>
            <span class="fileupload-new">Select file</span>
             <input type="file" id="file" name="file" value="" aria-required="true" required="" data-msg-required="Please select your file">
            </span>

            <a href="#" class="btn btn-default fileupload-exists" data-dismiss="fileupload">Remove</a>
            </div>
            </div>
            </div>
          </div>
           <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-sm-offset-3 col-sm-6">
              <button class="btn btn-info" type="submit" id="user-submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
          </div>
      </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Using xhr() could solve your problem... for example :-

```
var formData = new FormData($('#newUserForm')[0]);
$.ajax({
url: 'horoscope-check.php',
type: 'POST',
data: formData,
async: false,
xhr: function() {
    var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
    //if you want progress report otherwise you can remove this part from here to 
    myXhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(evt){
      if (evt.lengthComputable) {
        var percentComplete = (evt.loaded / evt.total) * 100 ;
        percentComplete = Math.round(percentComplete);
        $("#progress").text(percentComplete + " %");
      }
    }, false);
    //here
    return myXhr;
},
cache: false,
contentType: false,
processData: false,
success: function (data) {
    var res=jQuery.parseJSON(data);// convert the json
    console.log(res);
},

});
```